# Updating Arima in Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table, forecasting, arima

A very small version of my problem goes like this:

I have a number of time series

```
library(data.table)
library(forecast)
library(tidyverse)


 x <-arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.7), n = 100)
 y <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.1), n = 100)

data <- data.frame(x,y) %>% gather(var,value) # place into a data.frame
```

And I have modeled these with the fantastic forecast package, using auto.arima and data.table (in reality I have 400+ ts)

```
models <- setDT(data)[,list(model=list(auto.arima(value))), by = var]
```

Which works wonders, my question is **how do I update the Arima models for new data?**

I have been trying to do something along the lines of

```
models <-setDT(data)[,list(model=list(Arima(value, model = models$model))), by = var]
```

But am having no luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution  - but would love to know if there is a more R/data.table way to do this?

Note: As I was working to a solution, I changed the data to simulated ARIMA processes - to make sure the models were being updated correctly.

**Solution:**

```
x <-arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.7), n = 100)
y <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.1), n = 100)


data <- data.frame(x,y) %>% gather(var,value) # place into a data.frame

models <- setDT(data)[,list(model=list(auto.arima(value))), by = var]


x <-arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.7), n = 200)
y <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.1), n = 200)


data_updated <- data.frame(x,y) %>% gather(var,value) # place updated data into data.frame

data_updated <- setDT(data_updated)[, list(dat=list(value)), by = var] # turn this into lists

#Use a loop to update the models

for(i in unique(models$var)){

  models[var == paste0(i)][[1,2]] <- Arima(data_updated[var == paste0(i)][[1,2]] ,model = models[var == paste0(i)][[1,2]])

}
```